# How do I get pytorch working for my 765m?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pytorch, nvidia

Yes I know people have tried this again and again. There are so many forums about this issue but this is what I've been dealing with.

```
Specs:
Python=3.7
Pip=18.1
Cuda=10.0
cuDNN= 10.1
Kubuntu=19.10
GPU=gtx765m
```

I just want to mention I am pretty new to python and linux for that matter but I'm not an idiot. So please be thorough in your explanation.

With that out of the way let's get into what I've done. I've started looking into AI and the "real time voice cloning" in particular. https://github.com/CorentinJ/Real-Time-Voice-Cloning

What i've done is install pip, install all the components and then found out pytorch didn't support older GPUs (after playing around with CUDA for a few hours).

So I tried to "build/compile" it from the source to get it to work but now I'm stuck here:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
CUDA_cublas_device_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "THC" in directory /home/aydenrobert/pytorch/torch/lib/THC

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

(The full log is at: https://pastebin.com/B5nYNKjL)

I've searched through the whole of the internet for answers and I can't find any. This has taken me 2 days already and I am heading into the third. If someone could help me I would be forever grateful.

Comment: This issue seems very similar to yours: https://github.com/clab/dynet/issues/1457

Comment: @tyrion and that has an answer?

Comment: Well, as far as I understand, they solved it by upgrading CMake from 3.12.1 to 3.12.2

Comment: @tyrion oh I see I'll do that right away.